# Eclipse tabs closage within a project only

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Most of time I work with more opened projects at once which results in the overcrowded and fuzzy set of opened cross-projects tabs at once. Suddenly I realize I have found what I need and I want to close all the tabs belonging to a project. Is there a way to comfortably close all the project related opened tabs without closing a project itself?

**Example**

I have opened two projects *A* and *B*. I would like to close all the clases under the *B* project only, i.e. (*B1.java*, *B2.java* ... *B5.java*).

[image: Eclipse]

**Why don't you want to close the whole project and open to get rid of these tabs?**

I want to keep the project opened to see its structure and opened packages with their content. Although my example above is simple, let's assume I don't want to close the project and walk through a broadly branched tree to find a relevant package agian. The only I need is to close the currently opened tabs of the other project to be used soon or later.

**Close them manually, huh?**

Eclipse has an amazing feature that the each tab size is different based on the length of the class/file name - the closing of more of tabs at row is still about wasting time of finding the **x** button. The even more stupid is the expandable list on the right side of tabs which items have no **x** button at all so I can't close the tabs directly from it.

---

So, does exist a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is no, this is not possiable. To close all the tabs you can:

In the file menu(File>>Close All), click the close All item. Eclipse will close all the existing tabs.

This is quite a niche requirement, this could be quite a nice opportunity to build a Ecplise Java Plug-in.

Comment: I am aware of the right click to a tab and select *close*, *close others*, *close tabs to the left* and so on.  However it doesn't recognise to which project a tab belongs to :(

Comment: Yeah sorry there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using "Tasks" or "Mylyn".  When you move from task "A" to task "B", it will replace all the editor tabs for project "A" with the last editor tabs you had open for project "B".